# What is the "relay:" text in sendmail SMART_HOST value used for?

Tags: sendmail

What's the difference between:

```
define(`SMART_HOST',`relay:[1.1.1.1]')dnl
```

and

```
define(`SMART_HOST',`[1.1.1.1]')dnl
```

I've seen both used but don't see details in sendmail documentation on what exactly `relay:` means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`relay:[1.1.1.1]` explicitly specifies `relay` mailer (one of smtp based mailers).
It is `mailer:host` syntax.

`[1.1.1.1]` uses default mailer. It is `relay` mailer by default but it may be changed using `confRELAY_MAILER`.

"No mailer" version is ignored when `host` is listed on local email domains list (`$=w`) [See `SMailerToTriple` rule set].  It makes difference e.g. when **modified** `relay` mailer is used to relay to non standard port at `localhost`.